# Como remover notificação quando usuário mata aplicativo

Tags: android

Tenho uma notificação que aparece quando um serviço está rodando e desaparece quando para de rodar.

Se o usuário matar o aplicativo com o serviço rodando, a notificação fica lá para sempre.

Tem algum jeito de saber quando o usuário matou o aplicativo para eu remover a notificação? Como posso pegar esse evento?

Comment: Tentou utilizar o `onDestroy()`?

Comment: `onDestroy()` é só nas activities, não é? Não posso usar porque elas são destruídas em outros momentos que a notificação e o serviço devem estar vivos.

Comment: Pelo o que eu pesquisei, existe `onDestroy` para Services tambem, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy()

Comment: Mas creio que dessa forma não funcionará para você.

Comment: Realmente, eu até implementei ele aqui. Mas aparentemente não está sendo chamado quando o usuário mata o aplicativo.

Comment: Poisé não vai funcionar, pois identifica que o aplicativo foi fechado atraves do `onDestroy()` dá activity. No caso, mesmo se a activity fechar o Serviço ainda estará sendo executado, portanto ele não executa o `onDestroy` do serviço.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método [onTaskRemoved()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onTaskRemoved(android.content.Intent)) do serviço é executado quando o aplicativo é removido dos recentes.

Apenas removi a notificação nele.